# pull to refresh in case 'No data' widget

Tags: flutter, dart, pull-to-refresh, flutter-widget, flutter-futurebuilder

I need help in this please i have a RefreshIndicator that loads a ListView when there is data in the database however I want to make the widget return Text widget 'no data' if the table empty instead of the ListView.
but the when the table is empty it error appear 
**_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable')** 
and that will appear in the refresh method i don't know what should i do i appreciate any help thanks in advance.
this the UI for the page

```
class _onlineResultTab extends State<onlineResultTab> {
 List<ResultsModelClass> resultslist = new List();
 List<CoursesModelClass> coursesist = new List();

 ResultsModelClass resultsModelClass;
 CoursesModelClass courseModelClass;

 final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
 DataApiProvider dataApiProvider = new DataApiProvider();
 
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: RefreshIndicator(
       key: refreshKey,
       onRefresh: refreshList,
       child: _resultwidget(context),
     ),
   );
 }

 fetchResultDetails() async {
   final allRows = await DbHelper.mydb.getOnlineResultList();

   allRows.forEach((row) => {
         resultsModelClass = ResultsModelClass(
             "",
             row["Res_Stud_Index"],
             row["Res_Stud_Name"],
             row["Res_Sem"].toString(),
             "",
             "",
             row["Res_Batch"],
             row["Res_Courses"],
             row["Res_Grade"],
             row["Res_GPA"].toString(),
             row["Res_CGPA"],
             row["Res_Status"],
             row["faculty_desc_e"],
             row["major_desc_e"]),
         resultslist.add(resultsModelClass)
       });
   if (this.mounted) {
     setState(() {});
   }
 }

 fetchCourse() async {
   final allRows = await DbHelper.mydb.getResultcoursesList();

   allRows.forEach((row) => {
         courseModelClass = CoursesModelClass(
           row["Res_Courses"],
           row["Res_Grade"],
         ),
         coursesist.add(courseModelClass)
       });
   if (this.mounted) {
     setState(() {});
   }
 }

 List<String> listHeader = ['Student Results Details'];
 Widget _resultwidget(context) {
   final _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
   return resultslist.length == 0
       ? ListView.builder(
           controller: ScrollController(),
           itemCount: 1,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return Center(
                 child: Padding(
               padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _size.height * 0.4),
               child: Text(
                 "No Result Details !",
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
               ),
             ));
           },
           physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
         )
       : new ListView.builder(
           itemCount: listHeader.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             //var _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
             return SingleChildScrollView(
               child: Center(
                   child: Padding(
                       padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _size.height * 0.02),
                       child: Column(
                         children: [
                           Card(
                             elevation: 20,
                             margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                               horizontal: _size.width * 0.005,
                             ),
                             child: Container(
                               height: 50.0,
                               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                   color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor),
                               child: Center(
                                 child: Text(
                                   'Semester ' +
                                       resultslist[0].Res_Sem +
                                       ' Result  ',
                                   style: TextStyle(
                                       color: Colors.white,
                                       fontSize: 17,
                                       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                 ),
                               ),
                             ),
                           ),
                         ],
                       ))),
                    );
               },
          );
 }
```

the refresh method

```
Future<String> refreshList() async {
    refreshKey.currentState?.show(atTop: false);
    //await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    var studentIndex;
    final allRows = await DbHelper.mydb.MainInfoCehck();
    allRows.forEach((row) => {
          row["Stud_Index"],
          studentIndex = row["Stud_Index"].toString()
          //print( row["Stud_Index"].toString())
        });
    print(studentIndex);

    //void refreshResult(String studentIndex)async{
    await dataApiProvider.refresh_result(studentIndex);

    // }
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        coursesist.clear();
        resultslist.clear();
        fetchResultDetails();
        fetchCourse();
      });
    }

    return null;
  }
```

```
Future<String> refresh_result(String studentIndex) async {
    var url = main_urll + "?studentIndex=" + studentIndex.trim();

    final response = await http.get(url);

    List<ResultDetailsModel> ResulttDetailsListModel = [];
    final resultInfo = jsonDecode(response.body)['result_info'];

    DbHelper.mydb.deleteTableData("Result");
    print('Result informations : ' + resultInfo.toString());

    for (Map i in resultInfo) {
      ResulttDetailsListModel.add(ResultDetailsModel.fromJson(i));
      DbHelper.mydb.saveResultDetails(ResultDetailsModel.fromJson(i));
    }

    return "";
  }
```

Comment: I think it returns a null value or something like that for this reason it catches an error.

Comment: but my purpose is if it's return null or empty list it should display the no data found text why it's not working how should i make this condition to make it work

Comment: Hi did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if

`resultslist == null`  or `resultslist.isNotEmpty()`

for Handling empty list

Comment: i add the condition but the error didn't solved

Comment: Can you tell me that from which line does this error occurs? `_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable')`

Comment: from this line for (Map i in resultInfo) {
      ResulttDetailsListModel.add(ResultDetailsModel.fromJson(i));
      DbHelper.mydb.saveResultDetails(ResultDetailsModel.fromJson(i));
    } in the refresh_result method